# SDL2 C++ Program Behaves Badly if FullScreen Mode

Tags: c++, rendering, sdl, fullscreen

I'm making an app with SDL2.
I've gotten everything to work so far, including SDL_TTF. When I run my program in a normal window, everything works great!

However, now I'm trying to add fullscreen functionality... and I've run into the problem. On fullscreen mode ONLY, the program APPEARS to look fine at first, however, one of my functions (A text rendering function) causes problems. On fullscreen, this function momentarily removes or "flickers" the image behind it, revealing the previous image underneath. Why would this function cause an error on fullscreen vs. regular window sizing? I assume it's some kind of strange sizing issue...

```
void drawDialog(const char* content) {
//Draws a dialog box with set text
TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("assets/times.ttf", 30);
SDL_Color textColor = { 255, 255, 255 };
SDL_Surface* message = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, content, textColor);
SDL_Texture* dialogTex;
SDL_Rect destRect;

destRect.x = 50;
destRect.y = 730;

destRect.w = 300;
destRect.h = 30;

dialogTex = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, message);
SDL_FreeSurface(message);
SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, dialogTex, NULL, &destRect);
SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
```

}

Any help would be super! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have VSYNC on/off, and does toggling that make a difference?

Comment: Can you describe what 'momentarily' means? I'm not familiar with SDL, but one possible cause could be z-fighting of some of the planes due to the backbuffer not being cleared appropriately. Of course also check if the driver is causing this.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 I don't know what VSYNC is! What is it and how/where do I toggle it?

Comment: Pass `SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC` to `SDL_CreateRenderer` to enable it, and omit it to disable it.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Well, I just enabled it. Nothing changed.

Comment: @StarShine By "a little bit" I mean for the entire, exact duration of how long the text is on the screen. Sorry, I should've been clearer.

Comment: Just to make sure: How do you call this code? 60 times a second or just once?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Well, I call it repeatedly, but only once the user provides input. So, it'll draw a background, the user will input, and it will draw this text overtop. When the text is drawn overtop, that's where a problem arises. Nowhere near 60 times per second.

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 In the meantime, I've worked out a small fading subroutine - unrelated, for images. When I do a fade (alpha blending) in windowed mode, it looks great! But when I do a fade it full screen, it does a rapid flashing effect - a seizure enduing effect. I'm almost sure the two problems are related... what the hell is wrong with my full screen??? Everything works fine windowed!

Comment: It's hard to tell without more code. What SDL version are you using?

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 Oh, sure! What code would be helpful? This issue is so broad that I don't know what you would like so see, haha! I'm using SDL2 (Version 2.0.8, I think)

Comment: Yeah to be honest I don't really know what code would help either... maybe you could try to put together a minimal program that is able to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!
Before, when I created the window in the main function, I passed SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN to the window creation. However, the other mode of fullscreen is SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP which creates a "fake" fullscreen appearance by sizing the window to the screen size. This works perfectly!

Comment: Good find, I would not consider this a tue fix, but I can imagine you can do your thing and move on. Could you build a minimal sample and notify the SDL developers of the issue?